# lispy repl-loop substitution with IPython?

Tags: ipython, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to substitute this Lisp interpreter repl() loop with IPython.

http://www.norvig.com/lispy2.html

here is the full source code :

https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/lispy.py

Comment: Have you downloaded it and try to run it either with plain Python or Ipython?

Comment: when u run the lisp2.py you get into repl(), which is simple routine..that evals lisp expressions.. i want to modify it somehow so that it will run under IPython. if possible.

Comment: Another lisp-in-python is `hy`, http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/.  This works in Ipython.

Comment: thanks, but i'm modifying the language and this one is easier to mess with.. thanks anyway..

Comment: ooo it is lisp on top of python (i.e. lisp-to-python-ast i.e. full access to my python classes) it may work for me..